# Ruby on Rails - form input a column and insert another column in the form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form

There is a question about simple_form in Ruby on Rails.
I would like to create a form.

I have two model like: Vehicle, Repair.

```
 <%= simple_form_for(@repair) do |f| %>
   <div class="form-inputs">
     <%= f.input :vehicle_id, include_blank: true, label: 'Vehicle_no' %>
   </div>
 <% end %>
```

When I create the repair form, I would like to search @vehicle.no.
and When I key in the keyword about vehicle number like: XXX-1211 and I choose the one I need, then I could get the id with @vehicle.no to placing with the vehicle number.

How could I achieve with that?

Thank you!

```
> Updated
```

I have a input area to search for the Vehicle Number, but that value would be Vehicle id.

Form => Vehicle No [_____]  <= input the vehicle.no, but I would like to put the value about the vehicle's id.

```
> Updated
```

[image: This is the form]
This is the form above.

[image]
And when I key in the part of the vehicle number, it could appear some vehicle number to be choosen.(Search Part)
[image]

If I choose XXX-112, and according to the below datatables, I could get the value id = 2 to submit the form.

1. Vehicle_tables

id  no 
1 XXX-111 
2 XXX-112 
3 XXX-332 
.
.
.
100 XXX-222

How could I achieve this goal?
It use some of AJAX function?

I would like to use the search method because I have many vehicles data...

Sorry about the English skill to clearify the question..... :-(

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking for. Can you refactor your question, in case I am not the only one? Are you looking to select an existing `vehicle` in your repair form?

Comment: I have a input area to search for the Vehicle Number, but that value would be Vehicle id.

Form =>
 Vehicle No [_____]  <= input the vehicle.no, but I would like to put the value about the vehicle's id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form#associations

`<%= f.association :vehicle, label_method: :no, value_method: :id %>`

This of course assumes that Repair has a `has_one :vehicle` line in its model file.

What this code will do is generate a select tag with all of the labels equal to the :no (which I assume is of the format XXX-1211), but the value of the select elements will be the vehicle_id

Now if you create a new repair, it will be a dropdown showing the @vechicle.no but storing @vechicle.id in the database.

To be able to search, you'll need some extra javascript library like [select2](https://select2.github.io) that turns a select box into an autocomplete element. Then you add `input_html: {class: "select2"}` to the f.input line above to use it.

Comment: But, if I would like to search first and then put the value in, how could I do with that?

Comment: @IanCheng if you could clarify *how* you hope to "search" the vehicle numbers (like, using what mechanism?) I could help with that. But by default an HTML <input> element doesn't allow searching, so I recommend researching select2 or something like it and doing something like I suggest above

Comment: I explained more about my question above~~~~~ Sorry about my English Skill.....  :-(

Answer (score 0):

```
<%= simple_form_for @repair do |f| %>
    <%= f.collection_select :vehicle_id, Vehicle.all, :id, :no %>
    <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```